# Upgrading Ubuntu 17.10 on 32-bit laptop

Tags: boot, upgrade, 17.10

All of the past upgrades of Ubuntu (from 11.10 up to 17.10) that I have successfully accomplished on my arcane but loved 32-bit laptop have been very easy.  So, about 2 months after 18.04 became available I tried the on-line upgrade to 18.04 knowing that 18.04 cannot be installed as 32-bit but, according to Internet chatter, a 32-bit 17.10 can be upgraded as 32-bit.

Cosmetically everything went well - no errors listed and the process completed normally.  On completion I rebooted (with "quiet" removed on /etc/default/grub) so I could follow what was going on.  During the boot, I saw from the messages that the new 18.04 was recognized and then, after many, many other messages the boot process stopped and would not complete.  My system was effectively hosed.

To recover I had no choice except to re-partition my disk, create a new partition from which to boot, re-install 17.10 on the new partition, boot it, mount my old system partition and mechanically migrated my files over.  I was not a happy camper.

With the imminent release of 18.04.1 I would really like to update my faithful 17.10 to this latest LTS but I am understandably gun-shy.

Has anyone had similar experiences of upgrading a 32 bit 17.10 version and, importantly, were you successful in generating a bootable 32 bit 18.04, and what did you do exactly?  All help and advice most gratefully accepted.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason you're sticking to 32 bit? I've got Lubuntu 18.04 running 64 bit on a decade old laptop without issues.

Comment: The main Ubuntu doesn't have 32bit ISOs, but currently I'm testing the Lubuntu 18.10 ISO (i386; 2x 2005 machines) and having great results.  I'd suggest using a flavor of Ubuntu anyway on a 32bit only machine (it's far lighter than GNOME)

Comment: I'm sticking to 32 bit because of (a) my own lazy inertia, and (b) that's really all my hardware will allow ... when I said old I meant very old.  As regards alternative *buntu flavours (British spelling, sorry!!) that would be plan B.  However, I have no experience in upgrading to another flavour and am slightly worried that this might prove more difficult than stick with Ubuntu and finding a way?